# snow at Zakopane in April?

Tags: skiing

We are thinking of going skiing in the Tatra mountains in Poland (on the Slovakian border), staying in Zakopane.

Is there likely to still be snow in the first week of April?

Comment: Generally, not in Zakopane itself. There are of course deviations, but as a general rule - no. Depending on the weather, in the Tatra mountains - yes. The higher the altitude, the higher chance of snow. Would not expect any snow below 1200 m. a.s.l. But, as it is only weather and we cannot forecast it precisely, I give it as a comment, as the question is unanswerable imo.

Comment: We can't forecast precisely, but "is there likely to still be snow" is not a request for a precise forecast. I think this is perfectly answerable based on historical weather data.